# scala subnet ip address check 0/8

Tags: java, scala, ip-address

```
import java.net.InetAddress

println(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0").isAnyLocalAddress)
true

println(InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.1").isAnyLocalAddress)
false
```

Can I check somehow with any java.net.InetAddress native method or with com.google.common.net.InetAddresses if IP address is from within the range 0/8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about those types. If by any chance you can use [`commons-net`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/), `SubnetUtils` include the functionality you are looking for, as in the following example:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.util.SubnetUtils

val subnetInfo = new SubnetUtils("0.0.0.0/8").getInfo

subnetInfo.isInRange("0.0.0.0")     // false
subnetInfo.isInRange("0.0.0.1")     // true
subnetInfo.isInRange("192.168.0.1") // false
```

You can play around with it [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/ypg56xmgQEuwRRb7YYuKdg/6).

Comment: I want 0.0.0.0 to be true

Comment: That seems to be because of https://github.com/apache/commons-net/blob/d5ad8ff7b8c640e8fd1947583c70cc28a4eb9653/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.java#L165-L167 which was introduced as a fix to this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NET-641 -- it looks like the proper behavior is for 0.0.0.0 to never be in range.

Comment: (at least for this library, not sure about the proper semantics)